# $.parseJSON on $.ajax - problem on parsing response

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I don't know why, but there is a problem I'm encountering with `$.parseJSON` when making an ajax call, I need to check whether the response contains JSON then continue to parse it with `$.parseJSON`, if it does not contain any JSON then it will print out the response in an element (which the response will contain some HTML).

I then tested if `eval` would do anything, which of course it did, but I don't want to use `eval` for this.

The code I've got:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'ajax.php',
    success: function(response)
    {
        var msg = $.parseJSON(response);

            //alert(typeof(response)); <-- returns 'string'

            //alert(typeof(msg)); <-- returns 'object'

            //alert(msg.error); <-- this doesn't work at all.

            //eval(response) <-- returns [object Object]

        if(msg.error !== '')
        {
            ajaxWindow.html(msg.error);
        }
        else
        {
            ajaxWindow.html(response).hide().slideDown('slow');
        }
    }
});
```

So how come it's not able to parse the JSON string? [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) clearly says:

> Takes a well-formed JSON **string** and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

But nothing is being able to be parsed, is this some kind of error, or perhaps a bug?

**EDIT:** The JSON:

```
[{"error":"Error loading template"}]
```

Comment: I've had some weird issues like that before, this worked for me in that scenario 

msg = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

Comment: Are you sure ajax.php is in the same directory as the URL from which the request is made?

Comment: Please post the JSON you're trying to parse. Also what do you get when you try `alert(msg)`? The `typeof` gives `"object"` for a lot of different types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an Array, so you need to access it by the first index.

Instead of:

```
alert( msg.error );
```

do:

```
alert( msg[0].error );
```

Comment: Ah yes, now I've noticed just right after your answer was posted, `[{}]` - array object, `{}` - object. jQuery API docs should have included that in the docs! :P

Comment: I have tried to parse `{"result":"success","msg":"Success"}` in javascript but i got value is `undefined` when i am printing `data.result` any solution???

Answer (score 1):

Use $.post if possible. It sets the Content-Type to HTML automagicly.